# Searching for recent code source for "Parallel scientific computing in C++ and MPI "

Tags: c++, parallel-computing, reference-request

I am learning C++ scientific computing with "Parallel scientific computing in C++ and MPI A Seamless Approach to Parallel Algorithms and their Implementation" since it kept coming up a lot in questions, [for example](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26681/a-good-simple-book-resource-on-parallel-programming-in-c-for-scientific-compu).

The problem is that it is really outdated and when compiling I get lots of errors. Up until now, I've been able to correct it. But now, as things get harder, I've got stuck...

My question is, does anybody know if the source code has been done recently? For example in a git repo or newer editions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the book you mention is very old. In fact, it misses the last two MPI standards (3 and 4), and every C++ standard from C++11 on. Secondly, know that MPI has officially no C++ bindings, so if you want to learn MPI you can use any MPI book and use the C interface.

That said, take a look at my book "[Parallel Programming for Science and Engineering](https://theartofhpc.com/)" which covers MPI and OpenMP, in C/Fortran/C++. For MPI it covers the MPL library which is a C++17 wrapper around MPI. Free pdf download and open repository with lots of examples.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should abandon that book and it’s code and have a look at Deal.ii and its associated [video lectures](https://www.dealii.org/) on learning FEM. Wolfgang Bangerth is a regular contributor here. You can use the book and Wikipedia as references if there’s something in the lecture videos you don’t understand.

Comment: I like the shout out, Bill :-)

Comment: The home page for the individual lectures is here: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos.html

Comment: I completely agree with Bill's answer: deal.ii is a wonderful library where you do really see how things should be done. But, I think the OP is looking for a more "didactical" reference. If you plan to learn parallel programming for scientific computing, then looking directly to such a library sounds honestly a bit too much. That's just the opinion of an undergrad :-)

Comment: Of course, based on his own post, I skipped over my friend and coworker, Victor Eijkhout's, book and materials, now given in his own answer. Both are great resources.